# how to fetch data of last 5 years and count name of same entry in last 5 years

Tags: sql, sql-server

hello everyone I want to fetch records form database of last 5 five years, and then count how many times the entry of same names occurred in last 5 years ? is ti possible ? please need some suggestion

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: As long as data for the last 5 years exists in the database, it will indeed be possible.

Comment: My suggestion is to add enough details in your question so that someone will actually be able to help you.

Comment: As @James Z suggested, please provide the table schema, test data and desired results in text format. Please refer to below links on how to ask good question. [stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056) & [spaghettidba](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: sorry Iam new on stack .. so learning about how to ask question :) thank you for your suggestions @James Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WHERE` to limit the years, `GROUP BY` to group on the names, and `COUNT` to do the counting.